# Not being relationships in laravel 5 db:seed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have three model 
 **Developer** model:

 migration:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('email')->unique();
$table->unsignedInteger('programming_language_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('language_id');
$table->timestamps();
```

and function

```
class Developer extends Model
{
  public function programming_languages() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProgrammingLanguage');
  }

  public function languages() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Language');
  }
}
```

**ProgrammingLanguage** model:
migration:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name')->unique();
$table->timestamps();
```

and function:

```
protected $table = 'programming_languages';

public function developers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Developer');
}
```

**Language** model: 
migration:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('code', 30)->unique();
$table->timestamps();
```

and function:

```
public function developers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Developer');
}
```

I want to make db seeder and being relationships between those. How can i do that?
I am trying: creating a factory **DeveloperFactory**

```
$factory->define(App\Developer::class, function (Faker $faker) {
 return [
    'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
    'programming_language_id' => function () {
        return factory(App\ProgrammingLanguage::class)->create()->id;
    },
    'language_id' => function () {
        return factory(App\Language::class)->create()->id;
    }
 ];
});
```

seed OK, But it doesnot make any relationships. just seed the data.
How can i do that by db:seed?

Answer (score 2):

Seed your languages and programming languages tables first, then query for records in the developer seeder.

```
return [ 
   'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail, 
    'programming_language_id' => App\ProgrammingLanguage::inRandomOrder()->first()->getKey(), 
    'language_id' => App\Language::inRandomOrder()->first()->getKey()
 ];
```

Comment: seed ok. but my developer controller index function: `$developers = Developer::find(1);
        return $developers->languages;` shows error.

Comment: Your developer model belongs to languages and programming languages, change hasMany to belongsTo

Comment: If you're having a problem with routing now, I would suggest opening a new question since your original one about database seeding has been answered. It will allow for more people to have a chance to leave meaningful answers. Please mark the answer as accepted if this is the case.

Comment: I have indicated my question db seed is OK. but it does not make any relationship and also mention in the question.

Comment: your answer is useful. but it does not make me out.

Comment: Change the relationships in languages and programming languages to hasMany instead of belongsToMany.

Comment: I have tried before you suggest. but nothing happened.

Comment: relationship: `“developer” has many “programming_languages” and ”languages”` & `“programming_language” and “languages” also has_many “developers”`

Comment: Developers BelongsTo ProgrammingLanguage. Developers BelongsTo Language. Language HasMany Developer. ProgrammingLanguage HasMany Developer. Are you setting the table in your models?